# Apache load balancing when the session id is in url

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing, mod-proxy, mod-jk

I really have no idea...

I have a java web application which stores the session id in URL rather than using cookies. I want to run the application on 2 tomcat servers and fronting them with an Apache server for load balancing.

```
            __ tomcat1
Apache ----/
           \__ tomcat2
```

By setting the `jvmRoute` to `tomcat1`in the Tomcat `server.xml` file, the url will become `http://url;jsessionid=id.tomcat1`. So it is possible to achieve session stickyness by looking at the url, and route it to the corresponding server.

I know that `mod_proxy` and `mod_jk` and do the load balancing, but their sticky session only work when the session id is stored in cookies. In my case, the session id is encoded in the URL. How can I do the load balancing?

Comment: @Santhosh should it not be =ROUTEID instead of =BALANCEID

Answer (score 4):

Maybe your configuration is wrong. Documentation is not specified sticky-session working only cookies.

> stickysession -   Balancer sticky session name. The value is usually set to something like JSESSIONID or PHPSESSIONID, and it depends on the backend application server that support sessions. If the backend application server uses different name for cookies and url encoded id (like servlet containers) use | to to separate them. The first part is for the cookie the second for the path.

So you can specify the sessionid like below.

```
ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/ stickysession=|jsessionid
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx for your help. But we find that the dynamic resources generated by the app does not contains session IDs in their URL. So we are forced to use cookies to store session id.

Answer (score 3):

For creating the sticky we need to add the following line in your configuration(mod_proxy)

```
Header add Set-Cookie "BALANCEID=hej.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/;" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED
```

Then specify the route name in the config

```
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
    BalancerMember http://tomcat sever1.ip:8080  route=AcZxv
    BalancerMember http://tomcat server2.ip:8080 route=AcXxv
    lbmethod=byrequests stickysession=BALANCEID
</Proxy>
```

And add these routenames to tcserver.node in  catalina.properties of tomcat servers

```
tcserver.node=AcZxv (tomcat 1st server)
tcserver.node=AcXxv (tomcat 2nd server)
```